# Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function

Tags: reactjs

A que se puede deber ese error en mi codigo?

```js
componentDidMount(){

let container = document.getElementById('body');

container.onscroll = function () {
  let height = this.clientHeight;
  let scrollHeight = this.scrollHeight;
  let scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
  
  if (height + scrollTop === scrollHeight) {
     this.setState({ display: 'loader'});
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: esta pregunta ya habia sido respuesta en este [sitio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045716/react-this-setstate-is-not-a-function) :), espero te sirva.

Comment: Gonzalo esto es stack overflow en español, te agradezco por el enlace pero de todas formas ya lo habia probado. Igual no cuenta como pregunta duplicada ya que stackoverflow en español es un foro diferente al en ingles. Ya que debemos considerar que hay gente que no sabe ingles, o simplemente no le gusta postear en ingles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando que container es un HTMLElement, no hay por dónde pueda tener un método `setState` asi que imagino que la idea de tu código es invocar ese método sobre `componentDidMount` o mejor dicho, sobre la clase que lo contiene.

Puedes probar declarando una referencia a `this` fuera del contexto de la función  `onscroll`.

```
componentDidMount(){
    let _this=this;
    let container = document.getElementById('body');

    container.onscroll = function () {
      let height = this.clientHeight;
      let scrollHeight = this.scrollHeight;
      let scrollTop = this.scrollTop;

      if (height + scrollTop === scrollHeight) {
         _this.setState({ display: 'loader'});
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Eso es de la vieja escuela ;). Una función de flecha te evita los clásicos `self`, `that` o `_this` xD.

Comment: Pero estás partiendo de la base que él usa un browser con ES6 o que al menos está transpilando con Babel. Mi respuesta es sin saber nada de su ambiente. (aunque la primera línea ya evidencia de qué va la cosa)

Comment: ¿React sin JSX ni ES2015? Creo que nadie sensato hoy en día escribe aplicaciones React usando ES5. Ya es hora de adoptar los nuevos estándares, con la aparición de Babel se acabaron los pretextos.

Comment: Podría ser riot.js tambien :)

Comment: Riot, Vue y Ember son algunas excepciones ;) aunque yo los uso con Babel igual. Me gusta usar ES2017 xD

Comment: xD @Guz tu ya sabes que uso Browserify :p